# What's the asm equivalent of replacing a char from a string to a char of another string?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

I'm trying to code strcat to learn assembly. I code on mac osx with nasm using 64 bit assembly, with Intel syntax.
Here's my result so far :

```
section .text
    global _ft_strcat

_ft_strcat:
    mov rax, rdi
    mov rbx, rsi

loop_s1:
    cmp byte[rax], 0
    jz copy_str
    inc rax
    jmp loop_s1

copy_str:
    cmp byte[rbx], 0
    jz end
    mov byte[rax], byte[rbx]
    inc rax
    inc rbx
    jmp copy_str

end:
    mov byte[rax], 0
    ret
```

The line `mov byte[rax], byte[rbx]` gives me this compilation error:

```
ft_strcat.s:17: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

It's really hard to get good info on assembly since there's so much different syntaxes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info has some links to resources.  The Intel insn set reference manuals detail every allowed encoding for every instruction.  (e.g. which combinations of immediate operand, memory source, memory destination, etc. are encodable.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `mov` which takes 2 memory operands. See the [instruction set reference](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf). You can go through a byte-sized register, for example:

```
mov dl, [rax]
mov [rbx], dl
```

Also note that the calling convention mandates some registers need to be preserved, including `rbx`. You could use `rcx` instead, or save/restore it.

Comment: It might be helpful to find an opcode listing which details all of the allowable (and unallowable) parameters. Perhaps this will be helpful. http://ref.x86asm.net/